# Upgrading from SpringBoot 2.6.6 to 2.6.7 changed behaviour with validation ( javax.validation.ConstraintDeclarationException: HV000151 )

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-validator

Just recently upgraded from SpringBoot 2.6.6 to 2.6.7, but despite the GAV for hibernate-validator has not changed *( both releases use `org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.2.3.Final` and `jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:2.0.2` )*, I noticed a change in behaviour using the validation API.

I was able to reduce it to simple test case to show the difference between 2.6.6 and 2.6.7.

**NOTE:** *I understand the reason why it fails and know the fix, but what I don't understand is why it only started to fail with SpringBoot 2.6.7 when Hibernate validator artifact did not change between releases.*

To demonstrate, here are the code and test cases:

1. First the POM file ( using SpringBoot 2.6.6 ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>validator</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

2. Then the java interface and classes :

```
package org.example.demo;

public interface WithNameOnCard {

    String getNameOnCard();
    void setNameOnCard(String nameOnCard);

}
```

```
package org.example.demo;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Getter
@Setter
public class MembershipCard implements WithNameOnCard {

    @NotNull
    @NotBlank
    private String nameOnCard;

    @NotNull
    private String membershipNumber;

}
```

```
package org.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

3. Finally, the test case :

```
package org.example.demo;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;
import java.util.Set;

public class ValidatorTest {

    public static Validator validator;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setUp() {
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        validator = factory.getValidator();
    }

    @Test
    public void whenPropertiesEmptyThenFailValidation() {
        MembershipCard membershipCard = new MembershipCard();

        Set<ConstraintViolation<MembershipCard>> violations = validator.validate(membershipCard);
        Assertions.assertTrue(violations.size() > 0);
    }

    @Test
    public void whenPropertiesNotEmptyThenFailPasses() {
        MembershipCard membershipCard = new MembershipCard();
        membershipCard.setMembershipNumber("123456");
        membershipCard.setNameOnCard("JOHN SMITH");

        Set<ConstraintViolation<MembershipCard>> violations = validator.validate(membershipCard);
        Assertions.assertEquals(0, violations.size());
    }

}
```

4. Run the test, and you get :

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running org.example.demo.ValidatorTest
< ... snipped ... >
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.196 s - in org.example.demo.ValidatorTest
```

5. Now change the POM file so that it uses SpringBoot 2.6.7 :

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
```

6. Run the test, and you get :

```
INFO] Running org.example.demo.ValidatorTest
<... snipped ...>
[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.17 s <<< FAILURE! - in org.example.demo.ValidatorTest
[ERROR] whenPropertiesEmptyThenFailValidation  Time elapsed: 0.026 s  <<< ERROR!
javax.validation.ConstraintDeclarationException: HV000151: A method overriding another method must not redefine the parameter constraint configuration, but method MembershipCard#setNameOnCard(String) redefines the configuration of WithNameOnCard#setNameOnCard(String).
    at org.example.demo.ValidatorTest.whenPropertiesEmptyThenFailValidation(ValidatorTest.java:27)

[ERROR] whenPropertiesNotEmptyThenFailPasses  Time elapsed: 0.003 s  <<< ERROR!
javax.validation.ConstraintDeclarationException: HV000151: A method overriding another method must not redefine the parameter constraint configuration, but method MembershipCard#setNameOnCard(String) redefines the configuration of WithNameOnCard#setNameOnCard(String).
    at org.example.demo.ValidatorTest.whenPropertiesNotEmptyThenFailPasses(ValidatorTest.java:37)

[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   ValidatorTest.whenPropertiesEmptyThenFailValidation:27 » ConstraintDeclaration
[ERROR]   ValidatorTest.whenPropertiesNotEmptyThenFailPasses:37 » ConstraintDeclaration ...
[INFO] 
[ERROR] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0
```

**NOTE:** Like I mentioned above, I understand the reason for the error so that the class and interface must obey the Liskov substitution principle.

The fixes for the error to go away are, either :

- Removing the setter method `setNameOnCard()` from the `WithNameOnCard` interface. OR
- Moving the validation annotations from the fields of the implementing class to the getter method of the interface. OR
- Moving only the `@NotNull` annotation from the `nameOnCard` field of the `MembershipCard` class to the `getNameOnCard()` method of the `NameOnCard` interface, while leaving the `@NotBlank` annotation on the `nameOncard` field in the class. *( This last fix I actually don't understand. What's unique about `@NotNull` vs `@NotBlank` that would cause this difference between 2.6.6 and 2.6.7 ? )*

What I don't understand why was this error **NOT** generated with SpringBoot 2.6.6 when the Hibernate validator artifact remained the same between 2.6.6 and 2.6.7.

So it must be something else that is causing this change in behaviour, but I can't pinpoint to what it is.

Comment: Spring Boot 2.6.7 [upgraded the Lombok version](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/30777). The new Lombok version propagates the field annotations to the generated getter and setter methods.

Comment: Hi @ChinHuang .. you are right. I have tried downgrading lombok to 1.8.22 with SpringBoot 2.6.7 and it does not error. Similarly, if I upgrade lombok to 1.8.24 with SpringBoot 2.6.6, it errors out like in SpringBoot 2.6.7.

Can you put your comment into an answer so I can accept your answer ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spring Boot 2.6.7 [upgraded the Lombok version](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/30777). The newer Lombok version [propagates the field annotations](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/3180) to the generated setter methods. As a work around, you can downgrade the Lombok version by setting the Maven property:

```xml
<lombok.version>1.18.22</lombok.version>
```

Comment: You mean Lombok 1.18.22, not 1.8.22. So it must be

`<lombok.version>1.18.22</lombok.version>`

Comment: Thanks. Corrected the Lombok version in the answer.